# Knitr intermittently fails to execute readLines on URLs, throws Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection to <URL>

Tags: r, knitr

I ran into a strange issue where `knitr` seems to intermittently throw errors when running `readLines` on a URL. The below line works in console every time, but it seems to fail 4 out of 5 times when I run it in knitr:

```
readLines("https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/top.json?t=month&limit=100", warn = FALSE)
```

And here is the full knitr file:

````
---
title: "testing"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r run, include=TRUE}
x <- readLines("https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/top.json?t=month&limit=100", warn = FALSE)
```
````

To add mystery to this problem, I noticed that some URLs tend to do better than others, e.g. if I use the following URL: `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv` (iris dataset) then it seems to work every time, whereas reddit does not. Perhaps is has something to do with the response time from the server.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any ideas how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It may seem odd, but having said that this sometimes works - have you tried clearing the `knitr` cache? It can cause some odd errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I can also confirm that this isn't related to my machine or network as I know other people who have experienced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two things are working towards this *not* working (at least two things). The first: this is a large file! The website takes too long. Therefore `readLines` interprets it as an error. The other issue is that the website tracks who is requesting the data and how often. If you request too many times in a row or too quickly, it rejects your request. (That's pretty standard website security.)

Using the package `httr`, you can set a `timeout` time. However, you probably won't need to set the timer because of how this function works.

What you get back from `GET` is more than the JSON data. To get the `content`, you have to use that function. For JSON specifically, used `"parsed"`.

````
---
title: "testing"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(httr)
```

```{r run, include=TRUE}
# get the website information and content
x <- GET("https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/top.json?t=month&limit=100",
         content_type_json()) # declare that the content is JSON

```

```{r collector}
# collect the JSON content
df1 <- content(x, "parsed")$data$children

# create an empty list for the JSON content without the "extra"
df2 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(df1))

for(i in 1:length(df1)){  # remove the "type = t3" from every JSON item
  df2[[i]] <- df1[[i]][["data"]]
}

```
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm aware of rate-limiting, but this isn't the problem here, I'm only making a single request. As for the amount of data and the size of the content, what still puzzles me is why does this function behave differently when it is executed in console vs an RMD file